# Laravel 4.2 n+1 without eager loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a table with products

```
products
------------------------------------------------
id  product_code    purchase_type   quantity
1   106             new             1
2   107             renew           3
```

and a pricelist for products

```
price_list
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id  product_code    purchase_type   minimum     maximum     unit_price
1   106             new             1           25          20
2   106             new             26          50          16
3   106             new             51          100         14
```

When I display the products on a page, I need to display the price with the formula

```
getPrice(product_code, purchase_type, quantity) for every product
```

Using

```
foreach(Product::all() as $product){
    {{ $product->product_code }}
    {{ $product->purchase_type }}
    {{ $product->quantity }}
    {{ PriceList::getPrice($product->product_code, $product->purchase_type, $product->quantity) }} - this one is the n+1 problem
}
```

**PriceList::getPrice()** is something like:

```
public static function getPrice($productCode, $purchaseType, $quantity){
    return PriceList::where('product_code', $productCode)
        ->where('purchase_type', $purchaseType)
        ->where('minimum', '>=', $quantity)
        ->where('maximum', '<=', $quantity)
        ->get()->first()->unit_price;
}
```

I can't seem to find a more efficient way.
And when I display over 1000 products, then it gets really slow.
I can't seem to find a way to use eager loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way with mysql,

```
SELECT
   `products`.`id` AS `product_id`,
   `products`.`product_code` AS `product_product_code`,
   `products`.`purchase_type` AS `product_purchase_type`,
   `products`.`quantity` AS `product_quantity`,
   `price_list`.`product_code` AS `price_list_product_code`,
   `price_list`.`purchase_type` AS `price_list_purchase_type`,
   `price_list`.`minimum` AS `price_list_minimum`,
   `price_list`.`maximum` AS `price_list_maximum`,
   `price_list`.`unit_price` AS `price_list_unit_price`
FROM
   `products`
LEFT JOIN `price_list` ON `products`.`product_code` = `price_list`.`product_code`
AND `products`.`purchase_type` = price_list.purchase_type
AND `products`.`quantity` >= price_list.minimum
AND `products`.`quantity` <= price_list.maximum
ORDER BY
   `products`.`id` ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d6ac/2

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to call model from inside loop to get data.

Instead of doing that, follow below way.

You should define [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) between Product and PriceList tables.

**In Model Product.php**

```
 public function price_list(){
    return $this->hasMany('PriceList','product_code');
 }
```

**In Model PriceList.php**

```
 public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Product','product_code');
 }
```

**In Controller File**

```
 $products = Product::with('price_list')->get();
 return View::make('your_view')->with('products', $products);
```

**In View File** (file must have extention **.blade.php** to use below syntax)

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
  {{ $product }}
 @endforeach
```

**Note**:- Print $products in controller to check results.

Comment: Tried $products = Product::with('price_list')->get();
I need to return the product that match all 3 conditions: getPrice($productCode, $purchaseType, $quantity)
It should return the price_list with minimum 1 and maximum 25 and purchase_type Renew licence but instead returned minimum 250 maximum 499. Is there a way to specify the condition like $products = Product::with('price_list', $query->where('price_list.product_code', 'product.product_code')->where('price_list.purchase_type, product.purchase_type))->get(); or something like that?